# Set caret position predictable in contenteditable with substring replaced by image element

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have a contenteditable div.  in which if I type :) than it should replace that to a emoji image other wise the text appear. when I type :) then the caret moves to left of the image. then I have set the caret position to the end manually.It is working fine if we continue writing, but If I come back and try to insert a emoji between the text than the caret position is moving to the end.

```
const el = document.getElementById('user-input');
  el.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/:\)/g, `<img src=${emojis[':)']} alt=""/>`)
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(?:<|&lt;)3/g, `<img src=${emojis['<3']} alt=""/>`)
    setCaretToEnd(el)
  }, false);
```

the setCaretToEnd function

```
 function setCaretToEnd(target) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  const sel = window.getSelection();
  if (target.childNodes.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (target.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'IMG') {
        range.setStartAfter(target.childNodes[i], target.childNodes[i].length)
      } else {
        range.setEnd(target.childNodes[i], target.childNodes[i].length)
      }
    }
  } else {
    range.setStart(target.childNodes[0], target.childNodes[0].length)
  }
  // range.selectNodeContents(target);
  range.collapse();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  target.focus();
  range.detach();
}
```

the setCaretToEnd() function is pretty messy trying different approach

1: set caret position should always allow to write new text
2: when :) is written then the caret should come to the right of the image

how to make it work.